# Is there a database option that is local and does not require lots of overhead

Tags: java, database, vb.net, sqlite

I need to create a local database for query purposes.  I wish to build and populate a database with data from a number of text files, do the queries needed, and then destroy the database since it is no longer needed.

I am currently programing it in VB.net but would eventually want to port into a java or like language so other platforms can be used.

I prefer something that does not require the user to download something else to make this work.  A person I asked did suggest SQLite but I am not sure how to load it internally.

Comment: You didn´t tell us about the quantity of the data - maybe there are possibitlites without a db.

Comment: All I wanted was a few option to consider.  I know what I needed and how to use databases.  The answer I got was exactly the type of reply I wanted.

Comment: As to the quantity from as little as 100 records to 100,000 records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java SDK includes [Derby Database](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/overview/index.html) - see the link.

That can be used without further download (only Java needs to be there of cause)

Comment: Thank you this, looks like it might be just what I am looking for.